# How to add a new key and value in null object?

Tags: javascript, angular, object

I have a `null` object. And I want to add dynamic key and object into that.

**Tried**

```
this.myObj[`${dayValue}`] = {};  //1

this.withDayTimeSlot[dayValue] = [targetValue];
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '5' of null at ...
```

My dynamic object will be look like this.

```
{
  '5':[],
  '6':[]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set properties in a `null` object. It needs to be initiated as an empty object `{}` first.

```js
this.myObj = {};
this.myObj[`${dayValue}`] = []; // [] since your desired value in the object is an empty array [] and not an empty object {}
```

Comment: Yes I know that but from backend API data I got `null` so I have set now ternary operator and this works fine now.   -->  `this.myObj == null ? {} : this.myObj;`